# how to set varialble

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my DB i have created a table named "coursePlaces" in which i have 7 columns and a number of rows.

Loading the php-file course.php I connects to the db and selects data from the table "coursePlaces" using it to echo a number of buttons with different id and value each:

```html
<?php
    /* CONNECTION TO DB */
    
    require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    /*  ACCESS COURSE AND GRADE VAR FROM URL WITH GET */
    $course = $_GET['course'];
    $grade = $_GET['grade'];

    /* SELECTS DATA FROM TABLE AND ECHOES BUTTONS WITH DIFFERENT ID AND VALUE DEPENDING ON TABLE CONTENT */
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM coursePlaces WHERE grade='$grade' AND course='$course'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<input type="submit" id="place-' . $row['placeName'] . '" value="' . $row['placeName'] . '">';
        }

    /* CONVERTS VAR TO USE IN JQUERY SCRIPT */
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'var grade = ' . json_encode($grade) . ';';
    echo 'var course = ' . json_encode($course) . ';';
    echo '</script>';
?>

    <script src="includes/global.inc.js"></script>

    <!-- DIV TO ECHO OUTPUT FROM PLACE.INC.PHP -->
    <div class="selectedPlace" id="selectedPlace"></div>
```

When clicking one of the buttons the value should be send to the file "global.inc.js" In which i have placed a script used to listen for clicks:

```js
$('input#$row['placeName']').on('click', function() {
    var place = $('input#place-$row['placeName']').val();
    if (place !='') {
    $.post('includes/place.inc.php', {place: place, grade: grade, course: course }, function(data) {
        $('div#selectedPlace').text(data);
    });
    }
});
```

My problem is, that I don't know what the name of the button id is - since it is created from a varchar in a database table. How do i bring this information over into my .js file, so the script posts individual value from button no matter what button the user presses on the courses.php.

Comment: have tried $(this).val() in Click Listner ..?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to set your variable with Ajax ( method POST ).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change code as below:

```
 $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function() {
    var place = $(this).val();
    if (place !='') {
    $.post('includes/place.inc.php', {place: place, grade: grade, course: course }, function(data) {
        $('div#selectedPlace').text(data);
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: ....additionally, that code will not run without giving you clear hints about the syntax error

Comment: please explain your answer in detail

Comment: Sorry, i missed character ', it should be 'input[type="submit"]'. I edited my comment. The code means when you click any button has type attribute = submit, it will be triggered

Answer (score 0):

set on click attribute when you echo your inputs:

```
echo sprintf('<input type="submit" id="place-%s" value="%s" onclick="yourfunction("%s", "%s", "%s") >', $row['placeName'], $row['placeName'], $grade, $course);
```

and separate this **yourfunction** function:

```
function yourfunction(place, grade, course){
 $.post('includes/place.inc.php', {place: place, grade: grade, course: course }, function(data) {
        $('div#selectedPlace').text(data);
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use a generic click handler instead of the one you are using.

If all button have one common class you can listen to the click of all.

Add class inputBtn to following:

```
echo '<input type="submit" id="place-' . $row['placeName'] . '" value="' . $row['placeName'] . '" class="inputBtn">';
```

Change

```
$('input#$row['placeName']').on('click', function() {
```

to

```
$('.inputBtn').on('click', function() {
  var btnID = $(this).prop('id');
  var spltID = btnID.split('-'); //split from the - & spltID[1] will contain the part that you required.      
}
```

This code is written like just for the sake of clarity. It is possible to make it more optimal like `split()` function can be called on btnID to reduce code line.